# .Net Core POST with x-ndjson header error

Tags: .net-core, ndjson

I have problem with sending POST request from .NET Core app when I added header
Content-Type: application/x-ndjson.
Without this header I have 400 error.

When I send the same request from Postman, with that header, all good and I have response.

When I removed header and add like this:
new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-ndjson")
I have 406 error(Not Acceptable)

Please, help me how I should send POST request from my app to retrieve data?

Comment: What is the content string? Can you share the capture of the postman when sending the data?

Comment: content is ndjson 
smth like this:

{"preference":"Car"}
{"query":{"bool":{"terms":{"color":"red"}}]}}}

post request from postman with content-type "application/x-ndjson" works good. but how send this request from backend?